# How the configure postgresql tokenization for full text search?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-9.5

This works as expected:

```
# select to_tsvector('SICK FOTOCEL VS#VE180-P132') @@ 'p132'::tsquery;
 ?column? 
 ----------
 t
```

However, when the '#' is replaced by a '/' i get

```
# select to_tsvector('SICK FOTOCEL VS/VE180-P132') @@ 'p132'::tsquery;
 ?column? 
----------
 f
```

This is because `VS/VE180-P132` is classified as a file token. This is not correct in our use case. How do i change this behaviour? For instance, dropping the token types email, url and file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change this behaviour unless you want to write a new parser in C.

But you can use the workaround of replacing certain characters in all strings before you use full text search on them:

```
SELECT to_tsvector(regexp_replace('SICK FOTOCEL VS/VE180-P132', '[/.]', ' '))
       @@ to_tsquery(regexp_replace('p132', '[/.]', ' '));
```

Comment: That workaround is really ugly. But if this is really the only way to do it, i have to accept this :)

Comment: You can also define your index like that, and it won't hurt so bad unless you have to type it by hand.